# Difference between 2 dates in quarters

Tags: php, datediff

I am trying to make a function that gives me the number of quarters between 2 dates as an integer. The dates passed to the function are usually quarter-end dates except occasionally when one of the dates is just an arbitary date.

Basically I want it to figure out what quarter the two dates fall into and give an integer difference in the number of quarters.

E.g.

```
Q1 2013 -> Q2 2013 = 1
Q1 2013 -> Q4 2013 = 3 
Q2 2012 -> Q2 2013 = 4
Q4 2012 -> Q1 2013 = 1
```

Here is my function. I realise it is poor and does not return the correct answer all the time but I'm hoping someone can help...

```
function quarter_diff(DateTime $d1, DateTime $d2){
    //difference in months
    $diff = $d1->diff($d2);

    return ceil((($diff->format('%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%m')+1)/4);
}
```

and a fiddle here: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/tiw-jx3

We can see theat when the date is in the month after the end of a quarter we don not get the correct answer.

Can anyone suggest an improvement??

Comment: The main problem with your function is that is computes the number of month chunks (rounded up), irrespective of quarter start/end. Also, you should be dividing by 3 and not 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert each of your dates into quarters, ***then*** do the math, much like your first example.
Some quick pseudocode:

```
Convert d1 to quarter and year -> d1.quarter and d1.year
Convert d2 to quarter and year -> d2.quarter and d2.year
Number of quarters = d1.quarter - d2.quarter + (d1.year - d2.year)*4
```

Use the absolute value of the result to get the number of quarters difference.

You can create a quick and dirty "quarter" function by dividing month-1 by 3 and adding 1 to the integer portion of the result. Assuming January = 1, December = 12 and Q1 = January through March. You'll have to make adjustments if Q1 starts elsewhere, such as July.

```
Q = (int)(month - 1)/3 + 1
or
Q = ceiling(month/3)
```

Comment: I reckon month->quarter is better expressed by `ceil($month/3)`

Comment: Sure. There are multiple ways to get it. Whichever is clearest to you. (I typoed the 3/4; fixed it in the edit.)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I opted for thanks to suggestion from [Maple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17657790/1606323)

```
function quarter_diff(DateTime $d1, DateTime $d2){
    //Returns the number of quarters between two dateTime objects
    if ($d2 > $d1){
        $dtmp = $d1;
        $d1=$d2;
        $d2=$dtmp;
        unset($dtmp);
    }
    $d1q = ceil($d1->format('m')/3);
    $d2q = ceil($d2->format('m')/3);
    $d1y = $d1->format('y');
    $d2y = $d2->format('y');

    return $d1q - $d2q + 4*($d1y - $d2y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in MYSQL:

```
SELECT (year('2016-06-30') - year('2015-07-01'))*4 + quarter('2016-06-30') - quarter('2015-07-01') + 1
```